# Mootools Request problem in Internet Explorer when SEF URLs used

Tags: joomla, seo, mootools

In my custom Joomla 1.6 component Mootools's Request does not work only in IE and when the language filtering  plugin is enabled.

I am using Mootool's Request for getting my response from the server side which I echo.

***SEF URL example:*** http://localhost/mysite/index.php/en/component/foo/113

***The request:***
    function theRequest (){

```
    var url = "http://localhost/mysite/index.php?&option=com_foo&task=search&view=foo&format=raw&param=foo"

    var a = new Request({
        method: 'get',
        url: url, 
        onComplete: function(response) 
        {
            if(response == 'empty')
            {
                 qresults.innerHTML = "";      
            }
            else
            {
                qresults.innerHTML = response;
            }
        }
    }).send();

}
```

***The problematic response***

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/></head><body></html>
```

***My guess*** was that it had something to do with the URL and in particular the language tag introduced after enabling language filtering..therefore I edited my router.php to also check for language and itemid vars..nothing helped!
Also tried to edit the Request and change to onSuccess and replaced .innerHTML to .set('html',response), still the same reply in IE!

Can you suggest something please?

Comment: Can you specify what version of IE? And how the response should look like? Have you tried more recent version of Joomla/Mootools. Basically this is an async request, try how the synchronous is working by specifying param "async: false" in your mootool request

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not Mootools related. Your response doesn't contain a  tag and even then I'm not sure it would be processed by IE I think. IE doesn't allow certain combinations of incomplete tags in AJAX responses, for example something doesn't work, but something does.